# Closure is smallest closed extension

Tags: functional-analysis

From [these notes](https://www.math.lmu.de/%7Emichel/closure_-_closed_ops.pdf):

> Let $T$ be a closable operator on a subspace of a Hilbert space. The closure $\overline{T}$ a distinguished
> extension, because if $R$ is any closed extension of $T$, i.e. $T \subseteq R = \overline{R}$, then necessarily $R = \overline{T}$. In other words, $\overline{T}$ is the smallest closed extension of $T$.

The author meant to write $R \supseteq \overline{T}$ instead of $R = \overline{T}$, right? Otherwise this would mean that the closure is the only closed extension, which is generally not the case, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the previous discussion on the graphs, it seems clear that you are right, since the topological closure of a set is indeed the smallest closed set containing it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the confirmation! Also the fact that the author wrote that the closure is the smallest extension suggests that in general there can be several closed extensions (one could try to find an example), which again suggests that he didn't mean to write that each closed extension equals the closure.